Translated and published page doesnt render properly but a default language page published do in wagtail cms
My problem is about how I can render my translated template, because I made a template according to wagtail cms do in the documentation(e.g blogpage page class is converted to blog_page.html as a template).
However, I don't understand how only my translated template just not find that template.
I am using 6.1 wagtail and django 5.0 with python 3.10.12
I read the docs that says this:

Wagtail stores content in a separate page tree for each locale.

I suppose could exist another tree that works for only Spanish version(no default language in base.py).
I just followed the docs to configure the urls.py:
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views
from .api import api_router
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    path("django-admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("admin/", include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    path("documents/", include(wagtaildocs_urls)),
    path("search/", search_views.search, name="search"),
    path('api/v2/', api_router.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path('search/', search_views.search, name='search'),
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # Serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = urlpatterns + [
    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's page serving mechanism. This should be the last pattern in
    # the list:
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
    # Alternatively, if you want Wagtail pages to be served from a subpath
    # of your site, rather than the site root:
    #    path("pages/", include(wagtail_urls)),
]


My settings related to recognized preferred language and enables translations in base.py is:

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True
WAGTAIL_I18N_ENABLED = True
USE_L10N = True # displays dates and numbers in user local format
USE_TZ = True
WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', "English"),
    ('es', "Spanish"),
]

And finally, my template is just getting the context variables and loading i18n tag(as is specified in django docs)  into my template:
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static i18n wagtailimages_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}

{% block extra_css %}

{% comment %}
Delete the line below if you're just getting started and want to remove the welcome screen!
{% endcomment %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/welcome_page.css' %}">
{% endblock extra_css %}

{% block content %}
    <break></break>
    <section class="banner">

        
        <div>{{page.hero_title}}</div>
        <div>{{page.hero_text}}</div>
        <div>
            <a href="{% pageurl page.hero_cta_link %}">{{page.hero_cta}}</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            {% if page.cover_img %}
                {% image page.cover_img width-400 %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="category">
        {% if index_category %}
            {% for category in index_category %}
                <h2><a href="{% pageurl category %}">{{category.title}}</a></h2>
                {% if category.specific.cover_img %}
                    {% image category.specific.cover_img width-400 %}
                {% endif %}
                <p>
                    {{category.specific.description}}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>There is not categories available yet.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </section>
    <section class="gallery-blogposts">
        <h3>Recent blogposts: </h3>
        {% if recent_blogposts %}
            {% for blog in recent_blogposts %}
                <div class="blog-card">
                    <div>{{blog.title}}</div>
                    <div>{{blog.published_date}}</div>
                    {% comment %}
                        maybe we can put the authors here.
                    {% endcomment %}
                    <div><a href="{% pageurl blog %}">See blogpost</a></div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div>There is not available BlogPosts yet</div>
        {% endif %}
    </section>
{% comment %}
Delete the line below if you're just getting started and want to remove the welcome screen!
{% include 'home/welcome_page.html' %}
{% endcomment %}


{% endblock content %}

At least works fine editing my locales pages:

Note: Appears the option translate only in my model TopicIndexPage and BlogPage:
My models are one2many relationships.

Where the structure model is RootPage > CategoryIndexPage > TopicIndexPage > BlogPage
class CategoryIndexPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    cover_img = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    collection = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailcore.Collection",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name=f'Document Collection'
    )


    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        context['topics'] = self.get_children().live()
        context['home'] = self.get_parent().get_full_url()
        # documents = get_document_model().objects.filter(collection=self.collection)
        # context['documents'] = documents
        return context

    subpage_types = [
        'base.TopicIndexPage'
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("description"),
        FieldPanel("cover_img"),
        FieldPanel("collection"),
    ]
class TopicIndexPage(Page):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=511)
    ajax_template = "base/topic_index_page_ajax.html"
    def get_template(self, request):
        if is_ajax(request):
            return "base/topic_index_page_ajax.html"
        return "base/topic_index_page.html"
    subpage_types = [
        'base.BlogPage'
    ]
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("description"),
    ]
class BlogPage(Page):
    
    stitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField("base.Author", blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateField("Published date",blank=True)
    
    body = StreamField([
        ("subheader", blocks.CharBlock(required=False, label='Subtitle')),
        ("paragraph", blocks.RichTextBlock(required=False, label="Paragraph")),
        ("image", ImageChooserBlock(required=False, label='Image')),
        ("quote", blocks.BlockQuoteBlock(required=False, max_length=255, help_text="Important phrase")),
        ("page_chooser", blocks.PageChooserBlock(required=False)),
        ("url", blocks.URLBlock(required=False, help_text="Enter a valid URL")),
    ], blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('stitle'),
            FieldPanel('authors', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
            FieldPanel('published_date'),
        ], heading = "Blog Information"),
        FieldPanel('body')
    ]
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Add extra variables and return the updated context
        context['home'] = Page.objects.parent_of(CategoryIndexPage.objects.first()).first()
        context['category'] = Page.objects.parent_of(self.get_parent()).first()
        blog_urls = []
        blog_urls = list(map(lambda blog: (blog.specific.stitle if blog.specific.stitle else blog.title, blog.get_url()), self.get_siblings(inclusive=False).live()))
        context['siblings'] = blog_urls
        return context

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('stitle'),
        #add a streamfield, but you need for a custom backend search
    ]
    #api fields available
    api_fields = [
        APIField('stitle'),
        APIField('published_date'),
    ]

My error says that doesn't find the template:
My runserver log says:
[05/Jun/2024 20:50:27] "GET /media/images/fox.width-400.png HTTP/1.1" 200 192137 [05/Jun/2024 20:50:27] "GET /media/images/indeer.width-400.png HTTP/1.1" 200 192058 [05/Jun/2024 20:50:27] "GET /media/images/abstract_1.width-400.png HTTP/1.1" 200 320373 
Not Found: /favicon.ico 
[05/Jun/2024 20:50:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4434 
Not Found: /algoritmos/ 
[05/Jun/2024 20:50:36] "GET /algoritmos/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3614  

And doesn't find the template in the browser also:
Using the URLconf defined in bblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
django-admin/
admin/
documents/
search/ [name='search']
api/v2/
search/ [name='search']
_util/authenticate_with_password/<int:page_view_restriction_id>/<int:page_id>/ [name='wagtailcore_authenticate_with_password']
_util/login/ [name='wagtailcore_login']
^((?:[\w\-]+/)*)$ [name='wagtail_serve']
The current path, algoritmos/, matched the last one.

It works if manually I type the url as "<hostname>/es/algoritmos" but the default page sends me withouth the prefix "/es/".
I read about how LocalMiddleware is choosing the preferred language, however it doesnt work despite of I configure two browsers for each language(es & en) in the config.
My question is:
Why doesn't automatically choose the prefix(/es/) when it refers to not default language?
I hope some of you guys has the answer, if it's a dump question, please forgive me :)
